# why isnt the code after pthread_join() executed?

Tags: c, pthreads

I am writing a simple tcp client for an IRC server that I have. So Im implementing this by having a writer thread and a receiver thread, however after the user quits the session, the program stops all execution after the thread has been stopped and just presents a scanf()-like output in the console.

```
void senderThread(void* context){
  for(;;){
    //setup here
    //gets user input and stores into char* msg
    if(strcmp(msg, "quit") == 0){
      printf("quitting...\n");
      free(msg);
      shutdown(clientdata->sockfd, SHUT_RDWR);
      return NULL;
    }else {
      write(clientdata->sockfd, msg, strlen(msg));
      write(clientdata->sockfd, "\n", strlen("\n"));
      free(msg);
    }

  }
  return NULL;
}




int main(int argc, char* argv[]){                                                                        
  //setup stuff here    
  pthread_t thread_id[1];                     
  pthread_create(&thread_id[1], NULL, senderThread, (void *) &clientdata);      
  printf("creating threads...\n");        
  pthread_join(thread_id, NULL); //for(;;) loop here    
  shutdown(sockfd, SHUT_RDWR);                    
  free(username);                                                                                        
  return 0;                                                                                              
}
```

this is a part of the code for the program, however when I type 'quit' into the stdin, nothing happens. the printf and the shutdown both fire, but then I am left just left with the terminal expecting input and the program not actually closing. none of the code after the pthread_join() is executed. Why is this?

Comment: Always compile with `-Wall` and eliminate the wall of warnings you get from gcc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&thread_id[1]` is a pointer to the *second* element in the one-element array. That will be out of bounds and lead to *undefined behavior*.

You then call `pthread_join` passing a pointer to the first *and uninitialized* element in the array. Again leading to *undefined behavior*.

I suggest you use a single `pthread_t` *value* (instead of an array), and use the address-of operator in both the `pthread_create` and the `pthread_join` calls:

```
pthread_t thread_id;                     
pthread_create(&thread_id, ...);
pthread_join(&thread_id, NULL);
```